# Create an file attachment on the fly without file access rights

Tags: android, kotlin

I would like to create a file attachment on the fly in memory eg. CSV file in an Android API 34 App. That I can send as an attachment, without the need to have file access rights. Is that possible?

Comment: Not in memory but on storage without needing any rights: getFilesDir() and getExternalFilesDir().

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is maybe Data store a more recent alternative? https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/datastore

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "file attachment" and "send as an attachment"? Are you looking to send something using `ACTION_SEND` and `EXTRA_STREAM`? Are you looking to upload something using `POST` and Retrofit? Are you looking simply to create something that the user can use themselves, such as attaching it to an email? Or are you looking to do something else?

Comment: yes, i am using ACTION_SEND and EXTRA_STREAM. Currently i got it to work. But the email Programm can not open the file because it doesnt have file access rights. But there are no rights like that in the settings. I believe its an API issue.

Comment: getFilesDir() and getExternalFilesDir() seem to be obsolete in newer Versions